# How to add left and right arrows to scroll slider without jQuery and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, scroller

how to add right and left arrows for scroller without jQuery or bootstrap ?

how to i add right and left arrows for below horizontal scroller. Without jQuery or bootstrap. Thank you.

The scroll bar now is mobile friendly and scrolling with finger

Has any idea how to take it

Like:- <    >

Demo image:- https://ibb.co/mmPWLL

```css
#card_slider {
  clear: both;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 235px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#card_slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5px;
}

#card_slider::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#card_slider::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #5d646c;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#card_track {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2000px;
}

.subject_card {
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 215px;
  width: 178px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #5d646c;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgb(82, 82, 88);
}

.subject_card > img {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  width: 178px;
  height: 135px;
  display: block;
}

.subject_card > p {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="card_slider">
  <div id="card_track">
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src="  " />
        <p>Title #1</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #2</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #3</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="subject_card">
        <img src=" " />
        <p>Title #4</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two buttons, Something like this.

```
  <button  onclick="showImage(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button  conclick="showImage(+1)">&#10095;</button>
```

and write the javascript function something like this to select the images

```
function(showImage(n){
var y;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
for (y= 0; y < x.length; y++) {
    x[y].style.display = "none"; 
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Hope it helps